# How to change react native BottomTabNavigator colour dynamically

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to change the bottom tab bar color by changing a prop or state inside the app screen

if we can pass redux store would be better

here is my tab navigation

```
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import NotificationStack from './NotificationStack';
import SettingStack from './SettingStack';

const SupervisorTab = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    NotificationStack,
    SettingStack,
  },
  {
    resetOnBlur: true,
    tabBarOptions: {
      keyboardHidesTabBar: true,
      activeTintColor: '#F26D21',
      style: {
        borderWidth: 0,
        backgroundColor: '#000000', //need change this color code as per prop
        borderTopColor: '#000000',
      },
    },
    initialRouteName: 'SupervisorStack',
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      header: null,
    }),
  },
);

export default SupervisorTab;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work, but try using a variable to store the value of Background colour.

Other way would be to use proper styles definition and change the style class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set it as default through a defaultNavigationOptions function

```
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import NotificationStack from './NotificationStack';
import SettingStack from './SettingStack';

const SupervisorTab = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    NotificationStack,
    SettingStack,
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation, screenProps }) => {
      const mycolor = screenProps['mycolor'] || '#000000';

      return {
        tabBarOptions: {
          keyboardHidesTabBar: true,
          activeTintColor: '#F26D21',
          style: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            backgroundColor: mycolor, //need change this color code as per prop
            borderTopColor: '#000000',
          },
        },
      }
  },
    resetOnBlur: true,
    initialRouteName: 'SupervisorStack',
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      header: null,
    }),
  },
);

export default SupervisorTab;
```

then you use it

```
<SupervisorTab screenProps={{mycolor:this.state.mycolor}} />
```